# bxSlider one slide 100% height

Tags: slider, height, fullscreen, bxslider

I have a problem with bxSlider on one slide "referencie" I need set 100% height but with no luck, examle you can view at [g.fancystudio.sk](http://g.fancystudio.sk)

Answer (score 1):

bxslider provides that option.

Use the option 'adaptiveHeight'
    Dynamically adjust slider height based on each slide's height

default: false
    options: boolean (true / false)

```
 $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  adaptiveHeight: true,
  mode: 'slide'
 });
```